# Composite join on two CSV files in C#

Tags: c#

Starting from a table of daily fruit prices

**fruits.csv**

```
Day,Name,Kind,Price
2019-09-04,"apple","red",63.09
2019-09-04,"apple","yellow",52.14
2019-09-04,"orange","navel",41.18
2019-09-04,"orange","blood",41.18
2019-09-03,"apple","red",63.07
2019-09-03,"apple","yellow",52.11
2019-09-03,"orange","navel",41.13
2019-09-03,"orange","blood",41.13
```

I'd like to insert the reference prices by name *and* kind

**fruit_ref_prices.csv**

```
Name,Kind,Reference_Price
"apple","red",60.00
"apple","yellow",50.00
"orange","navel",40.00
"orange","blood",42.00
```

to result in the following table

```
Day,Name,Kind,Price,Reference_Price
2019-09-04,"apple","red",63.09,60.00
2019-09-04,"apple","yellow",52.14,50.00
2019-09-04,"orange","navel",41.18,40.00
2019-09-04,"orange","blood",41.18,42.00
2019-09-03,"apple","red",63.07,60.00
2019-09-03,"apple","yellow",52.11,50.00
2019-09-03,"orange","navel",41.13,40.00
2019-09-03,"orange","blood",41.13,42.00
```

The solution should be simple using C#'s built-in SQL-like syntax, and I'm sure the answer lies in one of the following tutorial pages:

- [Join clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)
- [Perform custom join operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-custom-join-operations)
- [Join by using composite keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/join-by-using-composite-keys)

but I'm having a hard time identifying the syntax of this language.

In my attempt below instead of writing

```
join fruit_ref in fruit_refs on fruit.name equals fruit_ref.name
```

I should be able to write

```
join fruit_ref in fruit_refs on fruit.name equals fruit_ref.name
and fruit.kind equals fruit_ref.kind
```

but the Boolean expression is not accepted. Why?

My attempt is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace MyConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        const string root = @"c:\path\to\here\";

        const string file1_in = root + @"fruits.csv";
        const string file2_in = root + @"fruit_ref_prices.csv";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Fruit_Basket fruit_basket = new Fruit_Basket(file1_in, file2_in);
            fruit_basket.PrintFruits();
        }
    }
    public class Fruit
    {
        public DateTime day { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string kind { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }

        public Fruit(DateTime newFruit_day,
                     string newFruit_name,
                     string newFruit_kind,
                     decimal newFruit_price)

        {
            this.day   = newFruit_day;
            this.name  = newFruit_name;
            this.kind  = newFruit_kind;
            this.price = newFruit_price;
        }
    }
    public class Fruit_Ref
    {
        public string name;
        public string kind;
        public decimal reference_price;
        public Fruit_Ref(string newName, string newKind, decimal newRef_Price)
        {
            this.name = newName;
            this.kind = newKind;
            this.reference_price = newRef_Price;
        }
    }
    public class Fruit_Basket {
        public List<Fruit> fruits { get; set; }
        public List<Fruit_Ref> fruit_refs { get; set; }
        public Fruit_Basket(string file1_in, string file2_in) {
            build_fruit_list(file1_in);
            build_fruit_ref_list(file2_in);
        }

        public void build_fruit_list(string file_in)
        {
            fruits = new List<Fruit>();

            int count = 0;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file_in);
            string line = "";

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (++count > 1)
                {
                    string[] splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToArray();

                    var newFruit_day = DateTime.Parse(splitLine[0]);
                    var newFruit_name = splitLine[1];
                    var newFruit_kind = splitLine[2];
                    var newFruit_price  = decimal.Parse(splitLine[3]);

                    Fruit newFruit = new Fruit(newFruit_day,
                                               newFruit_name,
                                               newFruit_kind,
                                               newFruit_price);

                    fruits.Add(newFruit);
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }

        public void build_fruit_ref_list(string file_in)
        {
            fruit_refs = new List<Fruit_Ref>();

            int count = 0;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file_in);
            string line = "";

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (++count > 1)
                {
                    string[] splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToArray();

                    var newFruit_name = splitLine[0];
                    var newFruit_kind = splitLine[1];
                    var newFruit_ref_price  = decimal.Parse(splitLine[2]);

                    Fruit_Ref newFruit_ref = new Fruit_Ref(newFruit_name,
                                                           newFruit_kind,
                                                           newFruit_ref_price);

                    fruit_refs.Add(newFruit_ref);
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }

        public void PrintFruits()
        {
            var innerJoinQuery =
                from fruit in fruits
                join fruit_ref in fruit_refs on fruit.name equals fruit_ref.name
                select new { Day = fruit.day, Name = fruit.name, Kind = fruit.kind,
                Price = fruit.price, Reference_Price = fruit_ref.reference_price };

            Console.WriteLine($@"""Date"",""Name"",""Kind"",""Price"",""Ref Price""");

            foreach (var i in innerJoinQuery)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($@"{i.Day},{i.Kind},{i.Price},{i.Reference_Price}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be writing the equals condition as `on new { fruit.name, fruit.kind } equals new { fruit_ref.name, fruit_ref.kind }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also refactor your code to use the [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper) NuGet package for reading/writing CSV files.

First, You can make these classes to reflect the fruits, fruit references and final fruit structure.

```
public class Fruit
{
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Kind { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}

public class FruitReferencePrice
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Kind { get; set; }
    public string Reference_Price { get; set; }
}

public class FruitFinal
{
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Kind { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string ReferencePrice { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Day={Day},Name={Name},Kind={Kind},Price={Price},Reference_Price={ReferencePrice}";
    }
}
```

Then you can make two methods to return the rows of each CSV file into `List<Fruit>` and `List<FruitReferencePrice>`.

```
private static IEnumerable<Fruit> BuildFruitList(string csvFilePath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(csvFilePath))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not locate CSV at path " + csvFilePath, csvFilePath);
    }

    try
    {
        using var fileReader = File.OpenText(csvFilePath);
        using var csv = new CsvReader(fileReader);
        return csv.GetRecords<Fruit>().ToList();
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return Enumerable.Empty<Fruit>();
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<FruitReferencePrice> BuildFruitReferenceList(string csvFilePath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(csvFilePath))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not locate CSV at path " + csvFilePath, csvFilePath);
    }

    try
    {
        using var fileReader = File.OpenText(csvFilePath);
        using var csv = new CsvReader(fileReader);
        return csv.GetRecords<FruitReferencePrice>().ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return Enumerable.Empty<FruitReferencePrice>();
    }
}
```

Then you can perform a grouped join and output the merged result.

```
var path1 = "PATH\\fruits.csv";
var path2 = "PATH\\fruit_ref_prices.csv";

var fruitList = BuildFruitList(path1);
var fruitReferencePrices = BuildFruitReferenceList(path2);

var groupedJoin = from fruit in fruitList
                  join fruit_ref in fruitReferencePrices 
                  on new { fruit.Name, fruit.Kind } equals new { fruit_ref.Name, fruit_ref.Kind }
                  select new FruitFinal
                  {
                      Day = fruit.Day,
                      Name = fruit.Name,
                      Kind = fruit.Kind,
                      Price = fruit.Price,
                      ReferencePrice = fruit_ref.Reference_Price
                  };

foreach (var fruit in groupedJoin)
{
    Console.WriteLine(fruit.ToString());
}
```

Merged results:

```
Day=2019-09-04,Name=apple,Kind=red,Price=63.09,Reference_Price=60.00
Day=2019-09-04,Name=apple,Kind=yellow,Price=52.14,Reference_Price=50.00
Day=2019-09-04,Name=orange,Kind=navel,Price=41.18,Reference_Price=40.00
Day=2019-09-04,Name=orange,Kind=blood,Price=41.18,Reference_Price=42.00
Day=2019-09-03,Name=apple,Kind=red,Price=63.07,Reference_Price=60.00
Day=2019-09-03,Name=apple,Kind=yellow,Price=52.11,Reference_Price=50.00
Day=2019-09-03,Name=orange,Kind=navel,Price=41.13,Reference_Price=40.00
Day=2019-09-03,Name=orange,Kind=blood,Price=41.13,Reference_Price=42.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Please change the equals clause as `on new { fruit.name, fruit.kind } equals new { fruit_ref.name, fruit_ref.kind }`

Why you require this

The query has two anonymous types (one for left table and one for right table). So to compare those anonymous types, the linq statement should use new keyword

**Query :**

```
var innerJoinQuery = from fruit in fruits
                join fruit_ref in fruit_refs on new { fruit.name, fruit.kind } equals new { fruit_ref.name, fruit_ref.kind }
                select new { Day = fruit.day, Name = fruit.name, Kind = fruit.kind,
                Price = fruit.price, Reference_Price = fruit_ref.reference_price };
```